# Asp.net core 2.1 - Two argument HttpPost from form

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, model, upload, asp.net-core-mvc

is it possible to pass two arguments into one [httpPost] controller method?
I would like to pass a model and a file. 
To pass model i use:

```
CS    
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("prop1,prop2,prop3")] SomeModel model)

HTMLCS
<form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="prop1" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="prop1" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.prop1"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
             <label asp-for="prop2" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="prop2" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="prop3" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="prop3" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="prop3" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="prop3" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

And it works nice. 
But I would like to post a file too.
So i created a input

```
<label asp-for="FileName" class="control-label"></label>
<input type="file" asp-for="FileName" name="FileName"/>
```

And modified my method in controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("prop1,prop2,prop3")] SomeModel model, IFormFile FileName)
```

But it says that SomeModel does not contain a definition for 'FileName' :(

EDIT:
Accoding to https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2

> If your controller is accepting uploaded files using IFormFile but you
>   find that the value is always null, confirm that your HTML form is
>   specifying an enctype value of multipart/form-data. If this attribute
>   isn't set on the  element, the file upload won't occur and any
>   bound IFormFile arguments will be null.

Comment: Where is your model class?

Comment: Just a simple model with random 3 properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the following lines:

```
<label asp-for="FileName" class="control-label"></label>
<input type="file" asp-for="FileName" name="FileName"/>
```

Your are using strongly type `label` and `input` control for file but your model class does not contain any property named `FileName`.

Write your `label` and `input` control for `FileName` as follows:

```
<label for="FileName" class="control-label">FileName</label>
<input type="file" name="FileName"/>
```

Then your `form` must contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute as follows:

```
<form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    // Here is your input fields
</form>
```

Now everything should work fine and your `IFormFile FileName` parameter will have the selected file on post.